# Sorting an array of strings in an alphabetical order using pointers

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, string-comparison

I have a project where I have to create a program that would let users input names in any order. Then the program displays the names alphabetical order. Also all of this has to be done using pointers. Now my attempt at the program prompts the user to put in the names and it displays them, but I can't get it to sort them for some reason. Can someone please help me?

Here's my attempt at the program:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int list;
  char *names[20];
  char str[20];
  printf("Enter the number of names: ");
  scanf("%d", &list);
  fflush(stdin);
  for (int i = 0; i < list; i++) {
    printf("Enter name %d: ", i + 1);
    // gets(str);
    scanf("%[^\t\n]s", str);
    fflush(stdin);
    names[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(names[i], str);
  }
  void sortNames();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%s\n", names[i]);
  return 0;
}

void sortNames(char **name, int *n) {
  int i, j;
  for (j = 0; j < *n - 1; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < *n - 1; i++) {
      if (compareStr(name[i], name[i + 1]) > 0) {
        char *t = name[i];
        name[i] = name[i + 1];
        name[i + 1] = t;
      }
    }
  }
}

int compareStr(char *str1, char *str2) {
  while (*str1 == *str2) {
    if (*str1 == '\0' || *str2 == '\0')
      break;

    str1++;
    str2++;
  }
  if (*str1 == '\0' && *str2 == '\0')
    return 0;
  else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I assume that you're writing your own `compareStr` function for didactic reasons, but on the off chance you're not you may wish to use `strcmp` (from `string.h`) instead.

Comment: Can't you just use `qsort`?  Or are you required to write your own sort function?

Comment: @kopecs Yes, I am writing my own compareStr, it's a requirement.

Comment: @TomKarzes I have to write my own sorting function

Comment: I'm not clear on why you're taking `n` as a pointer in `sortNames`. Its also notable that your `compareStr` function never returns 1. What's the intended handling of `str1` being greater?

Comment: @H.S.I tried removing the fflush(stdin) statements, but that appears to make the program run worse. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not actually calling `sortNames`.  You're just declaring it, using old-style syntax that lacks a prototype for the arguments (which you should never do).  So as soon as you exit the loop that inputs the names, you're immediately printing them out.  `sortNames` is never called.

Comment: `compareStr(name[i], name[i + 1]) > 0` is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing only on the issues with sorting, the main one is that you never call the sorting function you later define. The line

```c
void sortNames();
```

serves only to *declare* a function with the identifier `sortNames` which takes any number of arguments of any types (probably not quite what you want to do). I would recommend revising this line to instead be

```c
sortNames(names, list); // Not &list because I'm about to suggest not taking it as a pointer
```

Then for the `sortNames` function itself, I'm not totally clear on why you take the length of the array to be sorted as a pointer instead of just passing the `int` itself. I'd recommend revising this function to instead be

```c
void sortNames(char **name, int n) {
  int i, j;
  for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      if (compareStr(name[i], name[i + 1]) > 0) {
        char *t = name[i];
        name[i] = name[i + 1];
        name[i + 1] = t;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One issue with this as it stands though is that the expression `compareStr(name[i], name[i + 1]) > 0` is always false. This is due to the fact that `compareStr` only ever returns 0 or -1. You could fix this by re-writing `compareStr` to correctly handle the case where the `*str1 > *str2`. One possible way to do this could be

```c
int compareStr(char *str1, char *str2) {
    if (*str1 == '\0' && *str2 == '\0') {
        return 0;
    } else if (*str1 > *str2) {
        return 1;
    } else if (*str1 < *str2) {
        return -1;
    }
    return compareStr(str1 + 1, str2 + 1);
}
```

Although if you're writing this to learn I'd suggest trying to revise your current iterative solution instead of just copying & pasting this version.

Finally, because you want to use these functions before you've defined them you should either move their definitions prior to when they're used (i.e., have `compareStr`, then `sortNames` and then `main`) or provide a forward declaration at the start of your file for these functions, i.e., add

```c
void sortNames(char **name, int n);
int compareStr(char *str1, char *str2);
```

above your `main`.

---

As others have noted you probably want to avoid `fflush(stdin)` as its undefined behaviour and I would recommend against [casting the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1):

**The problem here is that the function `compareStr` will never return a value greater than 0. It just tells you if the 2 strings are similar or not.**

For sorting, you need to add an extra logic as follows:

```
int compareStr(char *str1, char *str2) {
    while (*str1 == *str2) {

        if (*str1 == '\0' || *str2 == '\0')
            break;

        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    if (*str1 == '\0' && *str2 == '\0'){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(*str1 > *str2){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Besides this, you have to make a call to function `sortNames` as **sortNames(names, &list)** and make sure that function definitions are written in proper order or make use of function declarations.